# How should i write my test when my code is redis dependent

Tags: c#, redis

Recently I’m curious about writing good unit test that covers test scenarios  .

I have a method like this

```cs
public bool IsObjPropError(int p_id)
{
     var dataList = RedisCache.GetObjectListByPropid(p_id)

     if ( dataList != null || DataListCheckingUsingLinqReturnsBoolean )
          return true;
     return false;
}
```

So my question is :

How can i write test that covers test case since my function is dependent on Redis to return data. Therefore my redis would need to have such data before i can proceed next step ( either create data using system n run set p_id = the data i created in system ) .

I’m trying to avoid creating data in system n hardcode p_id .

Is there any better way ? .

Answer (score 4):

One approach to consider is to put the code that interacts with Redis into a `TalkingToRedis` class that implements `ITalkingToRedis`.

Have your code use `ITalkingToRedis` (preferably injected via IoC / DI - e.g. Autofac).

Then mock / stub `ITalkingToRedis` in your unit tests (using [NSubstitute](https://nsubstitute.github.io/) or something similar).

*This general pattern works with almost everything (whether it be Redis, or a file system, or Kafka, or whatever).*